# SQL Group by with merge

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables that I want to merge, something like this:

```
C1  C2           V1   V2
1   A            3    5
2   B            4    6
```

I want to append all rows from second table to each row in first table.
I want to achieve something link this:

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
1   A   3   5   4   6
2   B   3   5   4   6
```

Can this be done in OracleDB?
Or I should make two queries and merge them in my code.

Comment: Pleas re-read carefully the question and thing it through. Would *you* understand it only while reading it? You'll have to provide more information to define your goal. Apparently you want to `GROUP BY` on the first column, but what should happen with the second column is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want *window* function like that

```
select min(c1) over () c1, min(c2) over () c2, max(c2) over () c3
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This is strange.  If you have two rows in the second table, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 cross join
     (select max(case when seqnum = 1 then v1 end) as v1_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then v2 end) as v2_1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then v1 end) as v1_2,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then v2 end) as v2_2             
      from (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by null) as seqnum
            from t2
           ) t2
     ) t2;
```

You can manually extend this to more rows.

If you have an indeterminate number of rows, then you cannot do what you want using a simple SQL query.  A `SELECT` statement has a fixed set of rows.  You could do what you want using dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).

Or, you might simply want to use another representation for the `table2` values, such as JSON, XML, or a nested table.